# how to render the result of an asynchronous function in react

Tags: reactjs, async-await, promise

I have a react functional component, where I want to display the value returned by an asynchronous function. However, I cannot run `const a = await getData();` as I can only use `await` inside an asynchronous function. I have tried wrapping the code like:

```
(async () => {
    const a = await getData();
  })()
```

But if I do this, and then simply include `{a}` in the render then due to the settings my project is on, I get that `a` hasn't been defined. (if I just do const a = 'string' then it works, but obviously `a` will not have the results of `getData`). I run into a similar problem when using `getData().then`. Does anyone know how I can get the results of an asynchronous function and then actually render it?

Comment: Can't you store the value in the state variable when the asynchronous function is completed?
It would be great if you share some more content like how and where you are using that asynchronous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `useEffect` mate, from `react` which let you work with that easly as shown below

```
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react'

export const TestComponent = props => {
   const [results, setResults] = useState([]);//it at all you're expecting array

   useEffect(() => {
      const dataApi = async () => {
         const a = await getData();
         setResults(a);
       }
      //dont forget to call the dataApi() function as below
      dataApi();
    },[])

   //then below is you're rendered jsx mate,
  return <div>{results.map(data => <span key = {data.id}>{data.name}</span>)}</div>

}
```

Comment: Do you're async calls function inside `useEffect` after all its expensive backend call and its results will affect the state, so you need to mind very much on when and how the `getData()` gets called... in react renders